# Deleting Row in Pivot table by id

Tags: php, laravel

This is how the structure of my pivot table looks like

**category_product**

```
id

category_id --FK

product_id --FK
```

Now i my pivot i have data like

**category_product**

```
id    category_id    product_id
1        1             4
2        1             16
```

Now in my table, I am able to display all items for `category 1` which has `product 4 and 16`. I want to delete a `row 1` using the `id` but I can't get that working with my code.

**Code**

```
public function delete($id)
{
    DB::table("category_product")->whereIn('id', $id)->delete();      
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table"> 
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>Category No#</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>                
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($categories as $cat)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$cat->id }}</td>
                    <a href="{!! action('Controller@delete', 1) !!}">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size:20px"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have two `@endforeach` while you need only one.

Comment: @1stthomas it was a typo..check update

Comment: `whereIn` looks wrong.

Comment: The `id` in pivot table should be unique, so you can use `->where` instead of `->whereIn`.
And your html code looks wrong because you always pass 1 as `id` instead of `$cat->id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [detach method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) in order to delete rows from the pivot table

For example to detach product 4 from category 1:

```
$category = App\Category::find(1);
$category->products()->detach(4);
```

To detach a list of products for example 4 and 16 from category 1:

```
$category = App\Category::find(1);
$category->products()->detach([4, 16]);
```

The detach method can accept an array of ids